# Signal connection timed out when over VPN

Tags: android, signals, vpn, wireguard, pihole

I've a raspberrypi with pihole and wireguard installed. Pihole works fine, same for wireguard except Signal Messenger for Android. When I'm connected over VPN I always get a timeout.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /192.168.210.1 (port 8080) from /10.6.0.2 (port *****) after *****ms: isConnected failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) ...
```

I installed wiregurad with PiVPN script, hence I've a very simple config which looks like this:

```
 [Interface]
 PrivateKey = ***
 Address = 10.6.0.1/24
 ListenPort = ***
 [Peer]
 PublicKey = ***
 PresharedKey ***
 AllowedIPs = 10.6.0.2/32
 PersistentKeepalive = 25
```

The configuration on my mobile phone is also pretty straight forward.

My routing table looks like:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.1.2 metric 202 
10.6.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.6.0.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.2 metric 202
```

192.168.1.2 is my raspi and also my default DNS. I' don't understand why Signal is trying to connect to 192.168.210.1 and I get this exception only when connected over VPN. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks!